# StringBuilder capacity method

Tags: java, stringbuilder, capacity

I have been working for Java OCA Exam and just noticed that StringBuilder class has a capacity method. Everything had been fine until I read about capacity method. It simply tells to Java to assign a capacity to StringBuilder. But Java can increase capacity of StringBuilder if it requires. 
What I am asking, when Java requires more space for characters it could raise capacity of StringBuilder by ownself, why capacity() method is needed ?

Answer (score 2):

Normally, Java will allocate capacity as the string grows, but this may take several reallocations of memory (if you are building a large string piece-by-piece), which will create some overhead for the garbage collector.

If you already know the size that you finally require, you can pre-allocate sufficient memory to start with and then you only have one allocation.

The formula for reallocation is:

```
int newCapacity = (value.length + 1) * 2;
```

So normally the capacity is doubled each time the StringBuilder runs out of space. The default capacity is 16, so if, for example, you need to build a 1k string, it would take quite a few (6) reallocations to get there.

The same strategy applies for collection classes as well.

Answer (score 0):

> What I am asking, when Java requires more space for characters it
>   could raise capacity of StringBuilder by ownself, why capacity()
>   method is needed ?

As the size of the `StringBuilder` exceeds the actual capacity, it is which is actually done.

`capacity()` is specified as :

> Returns the current capacity. The capacity is the amount of storage
>   available for newly inserted characters, beyond which an allocation
>   will occur.

You can consider it as a way for clients of `StringBuilder` (and `AbstractStringBuilder` instances in general as `capacity()` is defined in) to control more finely the actual state of the current `StringBuilder` instance.
It could be for example used to optimize the next invocation of `ensureCapacity(int minimumCapacity)` to allocate only which is required.

Answer (score -1):

To answer your question i want to you to have look at hashmap or ArrayList class

**

```
public class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
        implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8683452581122892189L;
    /**
     * Default initial capacity.
     */
    private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;
//...
}
```

As arraylist is resizable but internally they have some size if you not define the number of element then it will create an array with size of 10 i.e, `DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;`
So if you exceed the 10 it will resize and create another array with bigger size and put the previous values but if you declare the size of ArrayList before then it will create that size of memory and you achive efficiency.